# Handling page faults with vec_ld

Tags: c, aix, simd, altivec

I have the following program to load a vector in to vector register.

```
char *buf = (char *)malloc(10);

vector unsigned char t = vec_perm( vec_ld( 0, (unsigned char *)buf),
                                   vec_ld( 15, (unsigned char *)buf),
                                   vec_lvsl( 0, (unsigned char *)buf)
                              );
```

If the buf is ending before the end of the page, like let's take the page is from 0 to 4000 address, and the buffer is starting 3990. The second `vec_ld` will align the address to address less than (3990+15) which will be equal to 4000.

If the page starting at address 4000 is not mapped, the program above will crash.

How to avoid the segmentation fault?

All I can think of is to use `memcpy` to copy the data from the buffer to vector register when the size is less than 16 bytes.

Comment: In general you need to design your data layout so that there is sufficient padding to support any 16 byte loads you might perform. Typically this means rounding up your array sizes to make them a multiple of 16 bytes and possibly adding a further 16 bytes for good measure (can make pipelined loops easier to support).

Comment: In your example, you want to load 10 bytes in a 16-byte vector. I suppose by a side effect, it may not cause a segmentation fault but the design (loading 10 bytes in a vector) seems to be wrong.

Comment: Also see [Avoiding invalid memory load with SIMD instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13029427/608639).